# How update RecyclerView when MessageCountListener() fired

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I want to update RecyclerView whenever new message arrived or a message deleted. In my code, i've done to get newly arrived message and save it into database. At this point, code works OK. Now i want to update RecycelverView. I also implemented **`Runnable`** which checks on every second if **`MessageCountListener()`** fired or not.

My code,

```
 class FetchingEmail  extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {


        String folderName;
        String host = "imap.gmail.com";
        boolean supportsIdle = false;
        IMAPFolder folder = null;
        Context context = null;
        Activity activity;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        FetchingEmail(Activity activity, Context context, String folderName) {
            this.folderName = folderName;
            this.context = context;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String ... desireEmailAddress) {
            fetchInbox(context, folderName);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params){
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            // Handle what you want to do if you cancel this task
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
//            ((ViewEmails)context).prepareAdapter(list);
            Log.d("sdffdgh23", "fist");
            Util.alertDialog(context, "sdf", "sdfs");
            prepareInboxGroupList();
            ((MainActivity)context).prepareAdapter(list);
            Log.d("sdffdgh23", "sdklfjs");
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        void fetchInbox(final Context context, final String folderName) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //create properties field
                        Properties properties = new Properties();
                        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
                        properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
                        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

                        Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }
                        });

                        IMAPStore imapStore = (IMAPStore) emailSession.getStore("imaps");
                        imapStore.connect(host, username, password);

                        if (imapStore.isConnected()) {
                            Log.d("MailPush", "Successfully connected to IMAP");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MailPush", "Not connected to IMAP");
                        }

                        final IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) imapStore.getFolder(folderName);
                        folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_WRITE);
                        Log.d("asdffghjh", folder.toString());

                        Folder[] fdr = imapStore.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
                        for (Folder fd : fdr){
                            System.out.println(">> " + fd.getName());
                            Log.d("sdflkj3242", fd.getName());
                        }

                        folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
                            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {

                                Log.d("sdfds34", "MESSAGE TYPE: " + e.getType());

                                try {
                                    Message[] messages = e.getMessages();

                                    FetchProfile fetchProfile = new FetchProfile();
                                    fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
                                    folder.fetch(messages, fetchProfile);

                                    DB db = new DB(context);
                                    String email = null;
                                    String emailId = null;
                                    String groupId = null;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                                        Address froms = messages[i].getFrom()[0];
                                        String emailAddress = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms).getAddress();

                                        String messageNumber = String.valueOf(messages[i].getMessageNumber());
                                        String from = messages[i].getFrom()[0].toString();
                                        String subject = messages[i].getSubject();
                                        String date = messages[i].getReceivedDate().toString();

                                        email = db.getByValue(DB.EMAILS_TABLE, DB.EMAIL_EMAILS, DB.EMAIL_EMAILS, emailAddress);
                                        emailId = db.getByValue(DB.EMAILS_TABLE, DB.ID_EMAILS, DB.EMAIL_EMAILS, email);
                                        groupId = db.getByValue(DB.GROUPS_EMAILS_TABLE, DB.GROUP_GROUPS_EMAILS, DB.EMAIL_GROUPS_EMAILS, emailId);

                                        Log.d("sdfsjdf4578", "from "+emailAddress+ ", "+email+" email id "+emailId+", groutid "+groupId);



                                        if (db.addInbox(messageNumber, from, subject, date, groupId)) {
                                            Log.d("sdfsjdf4578", "database updated");
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("sdfsjdf4578", "database NOT updated");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    db.close();
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }

                            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                                Message[] messages = e.getMessages();
                                FetchProfile fetchProfile = new FetchProfile();
                                fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);

                                try {
                                    folder.fetch(messages, fetchProfile);

                                    DB db = new DB(context);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                                        String messageNumber = String.valueOf(messages[i].getMessageNumber());
                                        db.deleteByValue(DB.INBOX_TABLE, DB.MESSAGE_ID_INBOX, messageNumber);
                                        Log.d("sldfkj34l5kjFired", "message deleted");
                                    }
                                } catch (MessagingException l) {

                                }

                            }
                        });

                        folder.addMessageChangedListener(new MessageChangedListener() {

                            public void messageChanged(MessageChangedEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("Message Changed Event fired");
                            }
                        });

                        startListening(folder);

                    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

and startListening() method:

```
private void startListening(IMAPFolder imapFolder) {
        Log.d("sdfds34", "startListening");

        // We need to create a new thread to keep alive the connection
        Thread t = new Thread(new KeepAliveRunnable(imapFolder), "IdleConnectionKeepAlive"
        );

        t.start();

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            Log.d("sdfds34", "Starting IDLE");
            try {
                Log.d("sdfds34", "Setting IDLE");
                imapFolder.idle();
            } catch (FolderClosedException fex) {
                //Server closes connection.
                Log.d("sdfds34", "FolderClosedException. Server potentially dropped connection. Retrying connection...");
                fex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                //Idle isn't supported by server.
                Log.d("sdfds34", "Messaging exception during IDLE: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Shutdown keep alive thread
        if (t.isAlive()) {
            Log.d("sdfds34", "Interrupting thread");
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }

    private static class KeepAliveRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final String TAG = "dfkj234j34954567";

        private static final long KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ = 1000;

        private IMAPFolder folder;

        KeepAliveRunnable(IMAPFolder folder) {
            this.folder = folder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ);

                    // Perform a messageCount check just to keep alive the connection
                    Log.d(TAG, "Performing a messageCount check to keep the connection alive");
                    folder.getMessageCount();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignore, just aborting the thread...
                    Log.d(TAG, "Interrupted...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    // Shouldn't really happen...
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unexpected exception while keeping alive the IDLE connection");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

RecyclerView code:

```
void prepareSentGroupList() {
        sentGroupList = new ArrayList<>();
        sentGroupList.clear();
        DB db = new DB(MainActivity.this);
        Cursor cursor = db.getDistinct(DB.SENT_TABLE, DB.GROUP_ID_SENT);

        if(cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            Util.Toast(MainActivity.this, "No Groups", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        } else {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String groupID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.GROUP_ID_SENT));
                    if(groupID != null) {
                        String group = db.getByValue(DB.GROUPS_TABLE, DB.NAME_GROUPS, DB.ID_GROUPS, groupID);
                        Log.d("sdffghgf", groupID);
                        sentGroupList.add(group);
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
    }

    void prepareAdapter(List<String> list) {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_main);
        AdapterMain adapter = new AdapterMain(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, list, isInbox);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved by adding `runOnUiThread()` on `MessageCountListener()`.

```
 folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
                            public void messagesAdded(final MessageCountEvent e) {

                                try {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            if(isInbox) {
                                                prepareInboxGroupList();
                                                prepareAdapter(list);
                                                Log.d("dfgfgghjhjk", "inbox");
                                            } else if(isSent) {
                                                prepareSentGroupList();
                                                prepareAdapter(sentGroupList);
                                                Log.d("dfgfgghjhjk", "sent");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    Thread.sleep(50000000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException dsaa) {
                                    dsaa.printStackTrace();
                                }
```